# Homotopy Type of Surface of Genus g

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Need help with the following exercise;

"Let M be a compact orientable surface of genus g. Prove that M with a point removed has the same homotopy type as 2g circles with a point in common."

I have really no idea how to start with this exercise. I have the intuition for the case of a torus but not for this general case. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Write the surface of genus $g$ as the quotient of a $4g$-sided polygon. Once you're at this stage, it should be easier.

Comment: Do you know what a CW complex is?

Comment: start with a torus, remove a closed disk from him, unfold the resulting surface, now retract until a wedge of two circles

Answer (score 2):

Here we assume that you know the basic construction of a genus $g$ surface via the fundamental polygon. If not, you should talk to your instructor about it before you work on this problem. Now assume this, you can look at Hatcher's [book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) page 5 and figure out from the fundamental domain's glueing maps. I suppose knowing CW structure on the surface will be helpful, but not necessary.